# "Failed to get composer template data"

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, composer-php, preview

When I run my URL on debugger it shows "Critical Error" and "Failed to get composer template data"

But when I share the homepage www.techlegends.in, the link preview works and in debugger it shows the correct preview along with the Critical Error.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET9Vw.jpg]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue and searched for solution.
It's an actual Facebook bug, which is being fixed right now: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/918385908182634/

In summary, you can fix this by making sure that article:author only contains Facebook user IDs or Facebook profile URLs.

Applied it and voila, it works.